# how to record a terminal session in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, shell, powershell

Linux and Unix have the `script` [command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)), which is quite useful:

> The script command is a Unix utility that records a terminal
>   session.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unix)) The scriptreplay command offers a replay function to
>   script.[2] The session is captured in file name typescript by default;
>   to specify a different filename follow the script command with a space
>   and the filename as such: script recorded_session.
>
> The ttyrec program provides the same kind of functionality and offers
>   several bindings.
>
> Recorded shell sessions can be shared using online services.[3] The
>   advantage of sessions recorded in this format from the usual
>   screencasts is that shell instructions can be easily copy/pasted from
>   the player screen.

What's analogous for Windows?

see also:

[Tool to record an interactive bash session to shell script](https://superuser.com/q/720580/55747)

[Record SSH terminal in linux](https://superuser.com/q/1288726/55747)

for the utility of the `script` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Powershell `transcript` command.

> The PowerShell console includes a transcript feature to help you
>   record all your activities at the prompt.

`start-transcript`

`stop-transcript`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687007.aspx